# SQL stored procedure not grouping rows together

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I have the below code. It basically takes values from a spreadsheet loaded in by an asp.net upload control. A document number is automatically assigned. I put the data into a temp table, and then select and insert the data from the temp table into my actual database table. The data is group so that it takes the minimum doc number, and date column (the ONLY columns that are different for the data). The data loads fine but for some reason it does not get grouped. Does anyone see any problems with the query itself?

```
    CREATE Procedure dbo.temptable
    (
        @DocumentBranchPlant varchar(12)
      , @DocumentType varchar(2)
      , @DEANumber varchar(9)
      , @DebitMemo varchar(25)
      , @DebitTotal float
      , @ErrorOverRide bit
      , @OnHold bit
      , @LastModifiedUser varchar(50)
      , @ResubmissionCode char(2)
      , @DocumentNumber float out 
    )

AS
begin

  declare @TransmissionDate datetime
  declare @JulianTransmissionDate numeric(18,0)
  declare @ShipTo float
  declare @CustomerName varchar(40)

  Set @DocumentNumber = scope_identity()
  set @TransmissionDate = getdate()
  set @JulianTransmissionDate =getdate()


  DECLARE @cb table
  ( DocumentBranchPlant     char(12)
  , DocumentNumber          float   
  , DocumentType            char(2)
  , JulianTransmissionDate  numeric(18,0)
  , TransmissionDate        datetime
  , DEANumber               varchar(9)
  , ShipTo                  float
  , DebitMemo               char(25)
  , DebitTotal              float   
  , CustomerName            varchar(40)
  , ErrorOverRide           bit
  , EntryComplete           bit 
  , OnHold                  bit
  , ManualEntry             bit
  , LastModifiedUser        varchar(50)
  , LastModifiedDate        datetime
  , ResubmissionCode        char(2))

  INSERT INTO @cb
  ( DocumentBranchPlant
  , DocumentNumber 
  , DocumentType 
  , JulianTransmissionDate
  , TransmissionDate
  , DEANumber
  , ShipTo
  , DebitMemo
  , DebitTotal
  , CustomerName
  , ErrorOverRide
  , EntryComplete
  , OnHold
  , ManualEntry
  , LastModifiedUser
  , LastModifiedDate
  , ResubmissionCode)
  VALUES
  ( @DocumentBranchPlant
  , @DocumentNumber
  , @DocumentType
  , @JulianTransmissionDate
  , @TransmissionDate
  , @DEANumber
  , @ShipTo
  , @DebitMemo
  , @DebitTotal
  , @CustomerName
  , @ErrorOverRide
  , 0
  , @OnHold
  , 1
  , @LastModifiedUser
  , getdate()
  , @ResubmissionCode)



  INSERT INTO dbo.CbTempTable
  ( DocumentBranchPlant
  , DocumentNumber
  , DocumentType
  , JulianTransmissionDate
  , TransmissionDate
  , DEANumber
  , ShipTo
  , DebitMemo
  , DebitTotal
  , CustomerName
  , ErrorOverRide
  , EntryComplete
  , OnHold
  , ManualEntry
  , LastModifiedUser
  , LastModifiedDate
  , ResubmissionCode)
  SELECT
    DocumentBranchPlant
  , min(DocumentNumber)
  , DocumentType
  , JulianTransmissionDate
  , min(TransmissionDate)
  , DEANumber
  , ShipTo
  , DebitMemo
  , DebitTotal
  , CustomerName
  , ErrorOverRide
  , EntryComplete
  , OnHold
  , ManualEntry
  , LastModifiedUser
  , min(LastModifiedDate)
  , ResubmissionCode
  FROM @cb

  GROUP BY
    DocumentBranchPlant
  , DocumentType
  , JulianTransmissionDate
  , DEANumber
  , ShipTo
  , DebitMemo
  , DebitTotal
  , CustomerName
  , ErrorOverRide
  , EntryComplete
  , OnHold
  , ManualEntry
  , LastModifiedUser
  , ResubmissionCode
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "does not get grouped".  Your query is correct.  I suspect that you are grouping by a field or combination of fields that uniquely identifies each row.

Comment: You insert a single row into the table variable `@cb`. `@cb` is only in scope for a single run of the procedure. So you will only ever have one row making the group by completely superfluous.

Comment: I mean the document number (the unique key) gets a new value which doesnt group the data. In the query when selecting from the temp table, I am supposed to take the min value of the document number so that the rows get grouped.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about adding more rows to the temp table @cb?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like the programming model for stored procedure are very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: One way would be to have a real (non-temp) staging table with an extra column called something like import_id. Create a new import_id each time a user kicks off one of these jobs. Build up the rows one by one, then have a step at the end that does the necessary group by when transferring from the staging table into your live table.

Comment: I like that idea. Couldnt I also load the data into the temp table and then do an update statement at the end of my stored procedure to somehow select and group the rows accordingly from the data already uploaded to the temp table in sql?

Comment: Updated question tags to indicate database type ie sql server.